# Table doesn't show

Tags: java, android, xml, tablelayout

I have created a table through TableLayout (id=myProducts_tableLayout) programatically but it doesn't show on the screen. Below is the XML code.

```
#`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:fillViewport="true">

  <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#ffffff">

        <!--  Header  Starts-->
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@layout/header_gradient" 
                android:paddingTop="5dip"
                android:paddingBottom="5dip">
                <!-- Logo Start-->
                <ImageView android:src="@drawable/real_time_bidding"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"/>
                <!-- Logo Ends -->
        </LinearLayout>
        <!--  Header Ends -->  

        <!-- Footer Start -->
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/footer"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="90dip"
                android:background="@layout/footer"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- Footer Ends -->

        <!-- All Products View -->
        <LinearLayout
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:padding="10dip"
              android:layout_below="@id/header">

              <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#153E7E"
                android:textSize="25px"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="serif"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="My Products"/>

            <TableLayout 
                android:id="@+id/myProducts_tableLayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:stretchColumns="0"
                 >
            </TableLayout>

            <!-- Link to Enter New Product -->      
            <TextView android:id="@+id/link_to_allProducts" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="213dip"
                android:layout_marginBottom="50dip"
                android:textColor="#153E7E"
                android:textSize="20px"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic"
                android:typeface="serif"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Back to All Products"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- All Products View Ends -->

    </RelativeLayout>   
</ScrollView>
`
```

Below is the .java code

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.my_products);       

String[] sampleTxt = {"txt1", "txt2", "txt3"};
ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
final TableLayout layout = TableLayout findViewById(R.id.myProducts_tableLayout);
layout.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(4, 5));

for(int i = 0; i < sources.length; i++)
{
    final TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
    final TextView t = new TextView(this);
    final Button b = new Button(this);

    final LayoutParams textparams = new LayoutParams(400,40); // Width , height
    t.setLayoutParams(textparams);
    t.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,10);
    t.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

    final LayoutParams btnparams = new LayoutParams(20,20);
    btnparams.setMargins(10, 20, 15, 0);    // (left, top, right, bottom)
    b.setLayoutParams(btnparams);
    b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.delete);


    t.setText(sampleTxt[i]);

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            layout.removeView(tr);
        }
    });

    tr.addView(b);
    tr.addView(t);
    layout.addView(tr);
}
```

Could any one please point out the error. And also I have no idea why did the eclipse ask to make TableLayout, TableRow, TextView, Button "final", otherwise it was giving me an error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the code which you did not copy.  You probably have:

```
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
```

but you want:

```
import android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams;
```

I would have thought the first one would have worked too since you are only specifying width and height, but it seems that it does not.  TableRow.LayoutParams is a subclass of ViewGroup.LayoutParams.  When you call b.setLayoutParams() or t.setLayoutParams, you have to pass as argument the LayoutParams for their *parent*, the TableRow.

Comment: Thank You for you reply :). Below are the import files but it still doesn't appear on the screen.


`import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams;`

Comment: Maybe try changing `sources.length` to `sampleTxt.length` in the `for`-loop (`sources` is not defined in the code you posted).

Comment: Also, you should probably remove the line `layout.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(4, 5));`.

Comment: OK Thank You. I will try what you suggested :)